# C how to reference variables in other variables

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C and I haven't been able to figure how I can reference variables in other variables.

```
int main () {

    const char *TOKEN;
    char *cmd;

    TOKEN = "some auth token";
    cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN;
    printf(cmd)
}
```

This apparently doesn't work. How can I assign the value of to `TOKEN` to another variable `cmd`

Comment: Both variables are pointers and have no string content. So with `cmd = TOKEN` which copies the pointer, to point to the same string literal.

Comment: You cannot "assign" a string in such a manner.  You will need to create a buffer to hold your string and then use string functions such as `strcpy` or `strcat` to copy a string into your buffer (careful with `strcat` as it usually results in Shlemiel The Painter algorithms)

Comment: You need to find a good tutorial on pointers.  5 seconds of google on C pointer tutorial gives lots of hits.  Sorry, this isn't Python :)

Comment: You can use something like `snprintf(cmdbuf, cmdbufsize, "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN)`.  But `cmdbuf` has to be a properly-allocated array of sufficient size.

Comment: You'll also need to find a good tutorial on C operators. `cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN;` assigns the pointer in `TOKEN` to `cmd`. The string prior to the comma does nothing in this context. In some languages the comma concatenates strings. Not in C.

Comment: Do you actually need to *store* the value of `TOKEN` in `cmd`, or do you just need to display it via `printf`?  If the latter, you could simply write `printf( cmd, TOKEN );`

Comment: What do you think `cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN;` does? Look up the **comma operator**. Here you simply assign `cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s";` and then there is a dangling `TOKEN` statement at the end that does nothing. Then you call to `printf(cmd)` (missing `';'`) attempt to print with the format `"some_cmd --auth-token=%s"` but with 1 too few arguments invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, there are two kinds of *intructions* in a C source file. Macros or other prerpocessor directives that are executed before actual compilation and true C expressions that are compiled after that preprocessing.

C is a rather low-level language, so variables have a type and can only contain a value of that type: here `cmd` is a pointer to char and can only contain... a pointer to a char (the only magic is that a null terminated char array is interpreted as a string by many functions of the standard library.

So in this line:

```
cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN;
```

the compiler sees some variables (`cmd` and `TOKEN`), a string litteral (`"some_cmd --auth-token=%s"`) an assignment operator (`=`) and a comma operator (`,`). First the parameters of the comma operator are evaluated: `"some_cmd --auth-token=%s"` decays to a pointer to its first character, `TOKEN` is evaluated to its value (it is a mere pointer) Then the comma operator is executed and the value of the expression becomes the value of the right member of the comma, here `TOKEN`. Finally, the assignment `cmd = TOKEN;` is executed. So it works perfectly but and does what you have asked, but it may not be what you wanted because in next line you try to print an uninitialized char pointer...

You have to possible ways:

1. a macro:

   ```
   int main () {

       const char *TOKEN;

       TOKEN = "some auth token";
   #define CMD "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN
       printf(CMD);
   }
   ```

   The preprocessing changes this to:

   ```
   int main () {

       const char *TOKEN;

       TOKEN = "some auth token";
       printf("some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN);
   }
   ```

   which will gives expected result
2. the sprintf function:

   ```
   int main () {

       const char *TOKEN;
       char *cmd;

       TOKEN = "some auth token";
       cmd = malloc(strlen(TOKEN) + sizeof("some_cmd --auth-token=%s") + 1;
       sprintf(cmd, "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN);
       printf(cmd);
       free(cmd);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I assign the value of to `TOKEN` to another variable `cmd`

Providing that the types of `TOKEN` and `cmd` permit it, one can assign the value of the former to the latter via the assignment operator, `=`.  In your code, the types of those variables *do* permit it, but what you seem actually to be trying to do is something different.

It looks like you were hoping this sequence of statements ...

```
TOKEN = "some auth token";
cmd = "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN;
printf(cmd);
```

(missing semicolon added) would have the same effect as this ...

```
TOKEN = "some auth token";
printf("some_cmd --auth-token=%s", TOKEN);
```

..., but C doesn't work like that.  Variables have values.  Values may be composite, comprising other values, but they cannot contain *variables*.

More generally, variables cannot contain C code (that is intended to be interpreted as such where the variable's name appears).  The C preprocessor does, however, have a *macro* facility that serves that purpose.  Macros are not variables, and in particular, they have no separate representation in a compiled program.  Their full effect is realized at compile time.  But that's exactly what you need for something that represents C code.

In your case, then, you might do this:

```
#define COMMAND_WITH_TOKEN "some_cmd --auth-token=%s", token

int main () {
    const char *token;

    token = "some auth token";
    printf(COMMAND_WITH_TOKEN);
}
```

That has precisely the same meaning as:

```
int main () {
    const char *token;

    token = "some auth token";
    printf("some_cmd --auth-token=%s", token);
}
```